# SFML Thread Initialization not Working

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

I am attempting to create a thread, but when I compile, the following error appears:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: GameServer, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Heatbeat.cpp
1>C:\Users\Will\Documents\OpenGL\include\SFML/System/Thread.inl(48): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>          C:\Users\Will\Documents\OpenGL\include\SFML/System/Thread.inl(48) : while compiling class template member function 'void sf::priv::ThreadFunctorWithArg<F,A>::run(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=void (__thiscall Heartbeat::* )(sf::IpAddress),
1>              A=sf::IpAddress
1>          ]
1>          C:\Users\Will\Documents\OpenGL\include\SFML/System/Thread.inl(79) : see reference to class template instantiation 'sf::priv::ThreadFunctorWithArg<F,A>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=void (__thiscall Heartbeat::* )(sf::IpAddress),
1>              A=sf::IpAddress
1>          ]
1>          Heatbeat.cpp(26) : see reference to function template instantiation 'sf::Thread::Thread<void(__thiscall Heartbeat::* )(sf::IpAddress),sf::IpAddress>(F,A)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=void (__thiscall Heartbeat::* )(sf::IpAddress),
1>              A=sf::IpAddress
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am attempting to have the thread accept a function with one argument, but this error is generated.  Here is my file:

```
void Heartbeat::prepareHeartbeat(ClientHandler clients)
{
    std::vector<sf::IpAddress> ips;


    for(int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
    {
        PlayerSession player = clients.getPlayers().at(i);
        sf::IpAddress ip = player.getIp();
        ips.push_back(player.getIp());
        std::cout << player.getIp() << std::endl;
        sf::Thread thread(&Heartbeat::heartbeat, ip);

        thread.launch();

    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: I have tried

```
sf::Thread thread(&Heartbeat::heartbeat, this, ip);
```

As well, but this returns the following error:

```
sf::Thread thread(&Heartbeat::heartbeat, this, ip);
```

Comment: `heartbeat` doesn't even have one parameter. It needs an object to operate on since it's a member function. I don't know about SFML, but in C++(11), it's a simple, `thread(&Heartbeat::heartbeat, this, ip)` assuming you mean to use the current object.

Comment: When I changed my line to that, I receive this error:
1>Heatbeat.cpp(26): error C2660: 'sf::Thread::Thread' : function does not take 3 arguments

Comment: Well then I guess SFML doesn't work the same way as the standard one. I'm not SFML documentation, so I can't tell you what SFML does to allow passing data.

Comment: Try using stdlib threading library, introduced in C++11. `#include <threads>´ in the file where you need it. I think there is no problem in using a different threading API than the one SFML uses... At least I use it instead of Allegro's threading library which I find cumbersome and unflexible.

Comment: I would like to keep using the SFML thread library, as it's more portable than the C++ 11 thread.  However, if I cannot get this fixed, then I will switch over.

Comment: If no one answers the question and you solve it by changing to std::threads you can answer your own question stating the procedure you made, maybe it will help others in the future, happy coding and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good SFML threading tutorial [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/system-thread.php). 
Please take a close look at the section "Common mistakes".

Simply put, the syntax does not allow you to do what you want to do with SFML's threads. No constructor takes three arguments.

You will need to std::bind your function and parameters or create a functor or make your heartbeat method static.